# What should be included in an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm finishing a battleship project. But everything is in one class. I would like to make it more object-oriented.

It is suggested that I should use: Cell (Abstract class), then Water, Misses, ShipSection as subclasses. What should I include in the Cell abstract class? What kind of methods, constructors. And how to use them in for example in the class "Water"?

Thank you

Comment: You generally begin by describing your problem domain, and then from there you go on to develop a domain object model that fits your problem domain (with all the relationships defined).  If you've ended up with a single class that has everything in it, then you've already done it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cell` class should include common functionality for all descendants and let them to implement differences. Lets find out what is different and what is common.

Common:

- all cells have to be able to be drawn
- all cells have to be able to be stricken
- all cells have state: is it stricken or not.

Different:

- every cell implementation has it's own method of drawing, depending on its state.
- every cell implementation has it's own reaction on strike: is it miss or hit.

During the implementation, you can find other examples of common and different functionality.

*By the way, if we analyze it, turns out that cell should to draw itself depending on its state (stricken or not). Because of `Miss` is a stricken `Water` cell, you don't need separate `Miss` class at all. Miss just stricken state of water.*

So, your `Cell` class can be looking like following:

```
public abstract class Cell{

   private boolean isStricken = false;

   public void draw(){
       if(isStricken){
           drawStricken();
       }else{
           drawNotStricken();
       }
   }

   public boolen strike(){
       isStricken = true;
       return isItHit();
   }

   protected abstract void drawNotStricken();
   protected abstract void drawStricken();
   protected abstract boolean isItHit();
}
```

And `ShipSection` just will implements differences:

```
public class ShipSection extends Cell{
    @Override
    protected void drawNotStricken(){
        //draw section
    }

    @Override     
    protected void drawStricken(){
        //draw section in fire
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isItHit(){
        return true
    }
}
```

Same way you can implement `Water` class (as you guessed, water will return `false` in `isItHit()` method). Now, for example, if you have class `BattleField`, that contains all cells and store them in arrays, usage can be next:

```
public class BattleField{

    Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell[rowCount][colCount] ;

    ....

    public void draw(){
        for(Cell[]row : cellArray){
            for(Cell cell : row){
                cell.draw();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean strike(int row, int col){
        Cell cell = cellArray[row][col];
        return cell.strike();
    }
}
```

This code is simplified, just to demonstration of general idea. As you see, our `BattleField` class knows nothing about implementation of cells, and use all cells as abstract `Cell`.

Keep in mind, this is just example of design of class hierarchy, and depending on requirements you can make your own, different from that. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For fields, think of what each class would have in common. Make sure you call `super` if you extend the abstract class. For abstract methods, think of a method that is necessary in each subclass. And make the constructor initialize the fields. The example I provided is just something simple. I would also add "get" methods for the fields in your abstract class if there are any.

```
public class Water extends Cell
{
  public Water(/*parameters*/)
  {
    super(/*parameters*/);
  }

  @Override
  public void speak()
  {
    System.out.print("I am water.");
  }
}
```